# How do I make a "save progress" and "load save" function for a text-only game?

Tags: python, game-development

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVfiN.png)

How do I go about saving progress in a text-only game if the only thing being saved is progress down a bunch of nested "if" statement paths? (No inventory, etc.)

I've heard of "pickling" but don't know what to do with the info I've found because I'm brand new to coding.

Comment: You would need to save the state of all the vars, such as `moneyback`. You also probably want to separate state from process, so that you can save/load state independently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one idea would be that you have a sort of counter.
After every If-Else point, the counter increases by one.

And around every If-Else point, you have a bigger if, which skips that If-Else if the counter is high enough.

Get the point? , I demonstrate with some pseudocode

```
counter = 0

if counter < 1:
Print("do you give the money?")
input("y/n")
counter += 1

if counter < 2:
print("he got angry. What do you do?")
(...)
counter +=1
```

Then to save the game, you store the counter in a txt file or csv file or json file or something.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more robust, you probably don't want it to be coded as just progress down a bunch of nested if-thens. You could make a new `class` for each Room / Encounter / Episode, and within the instances of that new class you might have some if-then series still.

Then, if it is all linear, you could have a `list` that just contains, in order, all of the Episodes. When you `save`, you could save a text file that just has the name of the Episode you are on. Then `load` would read that text file and get the name of the Episode that they saved in, loop through the list of all Episodes until it gets to the one with the same name, and start them in that Episode (at the beginning of it).

I'm not super familiar with pickling, but I don't think it'll do what you want. I don't think it is intended to 'save' a script mid-run, which is how your stuff is setup now. Instead, it stores objects (like a list, or dictionary, or something much more complex, like a machine-learning model that was training for 4 days straight).

All that said, the scope of your question might be a bit big to get a thorough answer here.